# Downloading a whole folder of files from URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, download

I'm writing a program/script in python3. I know how to download single files from URL, but I need to download whole folder, unzip the files and merge text files.

Is it possible to download all files [FROM HERE](http://bossa.pl/pub/metastock/ofe/sesjaofe/) to new folder on my computer with python? I'm using a urllib to download a single files, can anyone give a example how to download whole folder from link above?

Comment: You should combine BeautifulSoup and urllib, and then try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install bs4 and requests, than you can use code like this:

```
import bs4
import requests

url = "http://bossa.pl/pub/metastock/ofe/sesjaofe/"
r = requests.get(url)
data = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
for l in data.find_all("a"):
    r = requests.get(url + l["href"])
    print(r.status_code)
```

Than you have to save the data of the request into your directory.

Comment: How can I save this data(all files from url to folder on my computer)? Now program with this code writing me '404' and '200' in terminal.

Comment: These are the responds codes of the requests. 200 means sucsesfull and 404 means failed. Inside the for-loop you have the variables `l` and `r`. `l["href"]` is the filename and `r.content` is the binary content of the file. Look at the [request documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for more help.

Comment: Can you please share what method you used? The main question is still not answered.

Comment: @MelihDurmaz What do you mean with 'what method'?